# Azure Storage account firewall rules work for table but break blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage

If I add a firewall rule on my Azure storage account that only allows access from my IP address, I can still successfully access the table and queue storage in that storage account, but when I try to access any of the blobs or file storage, I get an error.

Using Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer, the error I see is 'Unable to retrieve child resources. This request is not authorized to perform this operation'

It seems crazy that the firewall rule would work differently for blob and table storage. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please detach that storage account in the storage explorer, then connect to it again?

Comment: How do you connect to your storage account in Microsoft Azure storage explorer? Azure account or connection string or a storage account key name and key?

Comment: It makes no difference whether I connect with an Azure account or a connection string. I also see the same problem if I try to connect to the blob store from the Azure Portal, or using Powershell. Table storage is still accessible in all of these scenarios.

Comment: Also, I've seen the problem on three separate storage accounts. These accounts are all in westeurope and in the same resource group.

Comment: could you show me more settings information about your storage account?

Comment: Thanks for following up Jason. I've figured out what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I finally figured this out. It's a bit embarrassing! It turns out that my company has two internet connections, and the firewall decides which one to use based on the name of the resource. So table and blob storage are accessed using different IP addresses. I only put one of these IP addresses in the firewall rules (the one that was being used to access table storage).

Thanks to Jason Ye for trying to help me out!