# Azure connecting to a Storage Blob as Private IP instead of Public IP

Tags: azure, networking, vnet

I am connecting to a client FTP Storage blob via FTP in Azure from a managed Azure VM. I want to force the VM's public IP to be used but it is forcing the Private IP connect, this can be seen from the client logs. What do i need to configure to force the use of the public IP?

Answer (score 1):

> Basically the vm from where you are trying to connect to and your
> storage account need to be part of same Virtual Network and Subnet.
> Check if the firewall is blocking and disable the firewall on the blob
> storage .

Also ***check in your case if both vm and azure storage are in same region:***

- ***Services deployed in the same region as the storage account use private Azure IP addresses for communication***.i.e; your VM uses the
  internal network (over ipv6 and not the VMs published IP addresses
  )to attempt to access the Storage so adding the public IP won't work
  as IP network rules have no effect on requests originating from the
  same Azure region as the storage account
- Thus, you cannot restrict access to specific Azure services based on
  their public outbound IP address range.Reference: [Configure Azure
  Storage firewalls and virtual networks | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal#grant-access-from-an-internet-ip-range).
- ***To allow same-region requests try to use Virtual network rules .***
- One way to try is by adding the Virtual Network subnet of the VM to
  the firewall rules and adding  `Azure.Storage` as service endpoint to
  the subnet. If added through Azure Portal the service
  endpoint will be automatically added .

Please check the **references:**

1. [Allowing azure storage connectivity to a public IP - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/491363/allowing-azure-storage-connectivity-to-a-public-ip.html)
2. [networking - Cannot to Azure blob storage from VM because of firewall - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64209227/cannot-to-azure-blob-storage-from-vm-because-of-firewall)